# compare file with 20 other files to count the number of matches

Tags: c#

i have 20 files  i want to compare it with master.txt file one by one if there are any match the program gives me the total number of matches between two files i try  with the below code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1

{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int found;
        int count = 0;
        string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\master.txt");
        string[] mastercontent = File.ReadAllLines(**ineed to pass more than filename** );
        foreach (string con in content)
        {
            if (mastercontent.Contains(con))
            {
                found = 1;
                count = count + found;
            }

            // else
            // { 
            //Console.WriteLine("no match");
            // }
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
}
```

i face problem with passing more than one file path to the File.ReadAllLines()

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string[] listOfFiles = {"file1.txt","file2.txt"};
List<string> allLines = new List<string>();

foreach (var path in listOfFiles)
{
    allLines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(path));
}

//allLines now contains the lines from all files in listOfFiles
```

Or use a dictionary for faster lookup

```
    string[] listOfFiles = {"file1.txt","file2.txt"};
    Dictionary<string,string> allLines = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    foreach (var path in listOfFiles)
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
        {
            if (!allLines.ContainsKey(line))
            {
                allLines.Add(line,string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take an array or list of the filenames you want to read.

I am just showing you the logic to implement. You can code it in appropriate manner.

```
string[] mastercontent = null;
foreach(string file in  filenames)
{
 mastercontent += File.ReadAllLines(file);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

put another loop at outer level or extract it out to another function/method `CompareWithMaster(strign fileName)' and you can pass list of file names to it.

you might want to make some optimizations first (maybe check for filesize and stuff)